# Ajax using JQuery with CORS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

What is proper way to call Ajax request using JQuery when dealing with CORS?

I use this JavaScript code for ajax call:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: setup.services_domain + "/?type=ajax_cart",
            data: g,
            dataType: "html",
            crossDomain: true,
            headers: {
                  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"
              },
            xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
            encode: !0
        }).done(function (a) {

        })
```

I always get an error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://www.services.mysite.sk/?type=ajax_cart&action=add&product_number=462374ML&quantity=1' from origin 'http://www.mysite.sk' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
```

Main site is `http://www.mysite.sk` which is shop, and I have subdomain for all Ajax & API calls `http://www.services.mysite.sk` called services.

Both for main site and services have set these headers:

```
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"
```

Websites runs on same server with Debian 9 and Apache2 as webserver.

I know that these settings aren't good for production use, but I test it on dev server, and I have problems with these Ajax calls, I just don't know what is wrong with it.

Comment: Are you requesting to an http:// or https:// domain? Maybe you are requesting an http domain, but are redirected to https. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSExternalRedirectNotAllowed

Comment: @Tim I am requesting HTTP, for dev server we have HTTPS disabled so there are no redirections to HTTPS.

Comment: If CORS is setup correctly you don't need to change anything in your JS. Also note that the `Access-Control` headers need to be in the response, so you can remove the, from your jQuery AJAX request. If this isn't working for you then you need to debug your server logic.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan If I remove `Access-Control` from JS then I get error: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: That's a server side error, not a JS one. It's just a coincidence it's appearing after you remove it from the request. Check the response in dev tools and determine what headers it has.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It doesn't even send request to backend (I didn't get response), this is screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/41HEyBW.png

Comment: Go to the response tab. Check headers there

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It's empty, it says "Failed to load response data".

Comment: Ok, that means that the request was sent but your server did not respond. Is there any status code shown with the request?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No, there is only that headers on that screenshot, there is no status code, tabs preview and response are empty, but if I visit that ajax url directly in browser it works.

Comment: That's because CORS doesn't apply to browser requests, only those made via client-side JS

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, I know, but I don't know why that Ajax is not working.

Comment: Because there's no CORS headers on the response. I know you stated you've added them, but it's clearly not worked, otherwise your request would be working. That is what you need to debug

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Some advice why they aren't here? I really don't know where can be problem, because if I visit that page directly that headers are there, so it means that they are loaded from .htaccess file.

Comment: I can't really help with that as I don't recognise the server language you're using. I'd suggest asking a new question about it, as your JS front-end is setup correctly.